# How may I use multiple ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Array, let

```
Array [
{
  "Name": "xyz",
  "age" : 20
},
{
   "Name": "abc",
  "age" : 30
}
];
```

I need to display with array inside ion-content. I may I do it....? Please suggest me.

Comment: You can go through [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)

Comment: what you want to show in view??can u give a sample view with this data

Comment: No, I am looking like <div ng-repeat = "<root condition>"> <div ng-repeat = "child condition"></div></div>

Comment: if you have array within array then only you can use root and child condition. but in your data you have only one array .

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
      <div ng-repeat="item in ArrayName">
      {{item.Name}}
      </div>
  <ion-content>
<ion-view>
```

Also, [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) is a good resource, checkout!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way

```
<div ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic  list</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <div ng-repeat="group in users">
          <ion-item class="item-stable">            
             Group {{group.name}}
          </ion-item>           
        </div>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>      
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/qv04L8hw/)**